# React typescript right way to type a FunctionComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm quite new at react and typescript.
Is this the right way to type a FunctionComponent ?

```
type ModalProps = {
  children: ReactElement<any>;
  show: boolean;
  modalClosed(): void;
};

const modal: FunctionComponent<ModalProps> = ({
  children,
  modalClosed,
  show
}) => (
  <Aux>
    <Backdrop show={show} clicked={modalClosed} />
    <div>{children}</div>
  </Aux>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is just fine, I would recommend the following based on the examples/repos I have seen online.

First, using `interface` instead of `type`

```
interface ModalProps {
  children: ReactElement<any>;
  show: boolean;
  modalClosed(): void;
}
```

This makes extending your interface easier. For example, if using MaterialUI

```
interface ModalProps extends WithStyles<typeof modalStyles> {
  children: ReactElement<any>;
  show: boolean;
  modalClosed(): void;
};
```

And Second, I have seen the following way of typing functional components more than anything else, although I am not sure if there is a valid reason behind it.

```
const modal = ({
  children,
  modalClosed,
  show
} : ModalProps) => (
  <Aux>
    <Backdrop show={show} clicked={modalClosed} />
    <div>{children}</div>
  </Aux>
);
```

**EDIT**:
One last thing I should add, which is also just something that is more of a standard than a rule is the way you declare functions.

```
modalClosed: () => void;
```

Comment: modalClosed: () => void; AFAIK this is the standard way in ES& modalClosed(): void;

Comment: const modal = ({
  children,
  modalClosed,
  show
} : ModalProps I think is better using FunctionComponent<ModalProps> with generic

Comment: @user3887366 Can you please quote some article or a popular repository that follows this? I would like to reference it if I change my answer. For example I found the [DefinitelyTyped react-redux repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-redux/v6/index.d.ts) using the method above. While the material-ui repo uses the method you and OP have used for defining functions.